# Joomla! 1.5 notification plugin when a new article has been posted

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I'm in search for a plugin for Joomla! 1.5 that notifies all the registered users on my site when I have published a new article. Are there any plugins available that could do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any, but it's a reasonably simple function to add. You could modify something like this plugin:
[Joomlapraise SubmitMailer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-&-groupware/authors/4398/details)

Just add a feature for mailing registered users rather than admins. You could use the following code.

Add the following to the XML file, just after the 'mailto_admins' section:

```
    <param name="mailto_users" type="radio" default="1" label="Notify registered users" description="Sends a notification to all Registered users">
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    </param>
```

Then add the following to the '.php' file, just after the 'send email to all admins' section:

```
    // send email to all registered users
if((int)$params->get('mailto_users') == 1) {
     $query = "SELECT email FROM #__users WHERE usertype = 'Registered' AND block = 0";
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $tmp_emails = $db->loadResultArray();

     if(!is_array($emails)) { $emails = array(); }
     $emails = array_merge($tmp_emails, $emails);
}
```

Comment: Please note that this solution only works for users actually in the Registered group; users in other groups, like Author, won't get an email.

Answer (score 1):

This tip was very useful indeed. Unfortunately the GNU version of this utility for Joomla 1.0 does not seem to be available from JoomlaPraise anymore so I had to hunt high and low for a copy. I then changed your code mod above so that it would work with the Joomla 1.0 version of the JoomlaPraise SubmitMailer Mambot and it nowdoes the job.  It is available from my site with the above change included:

http://lightquick.co.uk/jdownloads/automatic-email-notification-for-joomla-1.0.html

Please feel free to download the mambot and play with it.

Yereverluvinunclebert

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AcyMailing Business/Enterprise can do this with the "auto-Newsletter" feature:
http://www.acyba.com/acymailing/140-acymailing-autonewsletter.html

You should set the frequency to "0" and so a Newsletter will be automatically generated within 15 minutes after you create and publish a new article.